# Modificar código números poderosos

Tags: python, revisión-de-código

Me podrán hacer un favor. Verificarían o mejor dicho me modifican un programa para que me dé bien, al igual que éste. Porque lo creé para un examen y mi profesora me resaltó un punto donde me dice que está de más algo. Saqué eso y al correrlo me da error... Así que busco nuevos puntos de vista.

```
def Primo(n):
    cont = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n%i==0:
            cont = cont + 1
    if cont==2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Poderoso(n):
    c=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if (n%i==0 and Primo(i)):
            if( n%(i**2) != 0):
               c = c+1
    if c>0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

num=int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))

if(Poderoso(num)):
    print("el numero es poderoso")
else:
    print("el numero no es poderoso")
```

Esto es lo que le pareció de más a mi Profesora `if( n%(i**2) != 0):`

Comment: Podría ser más corto, `if n % i ** 2:`. ¿Será eso?

Comment: Para poder saber si tu implementacion es correcta o no, antes hay que saber qué es lo que se supone que debe hacer. ¿verificar si un numero es primo? ¿si es "poderoso"? ¿cómo se define esto último? ¿tienes casos de prueba en los que sepas qué debería salir? ¿qué error te da cuando quitas la línea que te dijo la profesora?

Answer (score 1):

Tu código es correcto. Si quitas esa línea dejaría de calcular correctamente si el número es poderoso o no. Quizás has entendido mal lo que te ha dicho la profesora y se refiera a que puedes quizás juntar ese `if` con la línea anterior, añadiendo otra cláusula `and`. Es decir, dejarlo así:

```
def Poderoso(n):
    c=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if (n%i==0 and Primo(i)) and (n%(i**2) != 0):
            c = c+1
    if c>0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

### Optimizaciones

No obstante, el cambio antes sugerido no afecta para nada a la eficiencia del código, que seguirá tardando exactamente lo mismo. He cronometrado cuánto tarda en encontrar todos los "Poderosos" menores de 101 y tarda **1.16ms**

Puede parecer muy rápido, pero se puede mejorar de varias formas:

- La función `Primo()` no necesita iterar entre 1 y `n`. Basta que lo haga entre 2 y la raiz cuadrada de `n`. Eso ahorra muchas iteraciones.
- La función `Primo()` no necesita contar cuántos divisores encuentra. Tan pronto como encuentra uno, puede retornar `False`, pues ya sabemos que el número no es primo. Sólo si agota el bucle sin haber encontrado divisores sabremos que es primo.

Es decir:

```
def Primo2(n):
  for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):  # n**0.5 es la raiz cuadrada de n
    if n%i == 0:
      return False
  return True
```

Análogamente la función `Poderoso()` no necesita iterar entre 1 y `n` sino que puede limitarse también a iterar entre 2 y la raiz de `n`. Y también puede retornar inmediatamente `False` en cuanto encuentre un primo divisor, cuyo cuadrado no sea divisor. Es decir:

```
def Poderoso2(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0 and Primo2(i) and n % i**2 != 0:
           return False
    return True
```

Esta implementación, además de tener un código más breve, se ejecuta más rápido. Tarda **383 µs**, que es aproximadamente un tercio de la otra. La diferencia será mayor a medida que se prueban números más grandes.

### Otro enfoque

Otra forma de abordar el problema puede ser crear antes una función capaz de *factorizar* un número que le pases. La factorización consiste en encontrar todos sus divisores primos. Por ejemplo, la factorización de 100 es 2x2x5x5, que puede escribirse como 2<sup>2</sup>·5<sup>2</sup>.

La siguiente función recibe un número `n` y devuelve su factorización en forma de diccionario. En ese diccionario cada clave es un factor primo, y cada valor es la potencia a la que iría elevado. Así, para 100, el diccionario resultante sería `{2:2, 5:2}`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def factorizar(n):
  fact = defaultdict(int)
  i = 2
  while i <= n**0.5:     
      if n%i == 0:      
          fact[i] +=1
          n//= i
      else:
          i+=1
  fact[n] += 1
  return fact
```

Con una función así, verificar si un número es poderoso es sencillo. Basta comprobar que todos sus factores primos están elevados a una potencia mayor de 1. Por ejemplo, el 36 es poderoso porque su factorización sale `{2: 2, 3: 2}`, en el que tanto el 2 como el 3 están elevados a 2. Por tanto es divisible por todos sus divisores primos al cuadrado.

Teniendo en cuenta esta idea, la implementación de `Poderoso()` podría quedar así:

```
def Poderoso3(n):
  if n == 1:
     return True  # Este es un caso especial
  return all(exponente > 1 for exponente in factorizar(n).values())
```

Esta implementación tarda un poquito menos (**284 µs**). La diferencia es mayor para números más grandes.

Por ejemplo, para verificar que el número 1000000 (un millón) es poderoso, estos son los tiempos invertidos en cada una de las implementaciones:

- `Poderoso`: 292 ms
- `Poderoso2`: 85.5 ms
- `Poderoso3`: 6.74 µs

No obstante, en comprobar que un número *no es poderoso*, la tercera implementación puede tardar más que la segunda.

Comment: Excelente respuesta @abulafia. Como siempre!

Answer (score 0):

Una de las cosas que podría sobrar, más que la línea de código que dices, es lo que hay dentro de ella, ya que estás contando cuantos cuadrados de sus divisores primos no son divisores del número.

Realmente no necesitas saber cuantos hay, con que haya uno ya sería suficiente para que el número no sea poderoso, por lo que si se da esa condición puedes hacer que salga del bucle devolviendo `False`.

Si no sale del bucle con ninguno, es que todos han cumplido y el número es poderoso.

```
def Poderoso(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0 and Primo(i):
            if n % i**2 != 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Acá te dejo una forma más compacta de escribir tu código, la cual puedes mejorar aún más con los consejos de Abulafia:

```
def Primo(n):
    primo=True
    for i in range(2,n):
        if not n%i:
            primo=False
    return primo

def Poderoso(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if not n%i and Primo(i) and n%i**2:
            return print('El numero es poderoso')
    return print('El numero no es poderoso')

Poderoso(int(input('Ingrese un numero: ')))
```